# Annotating image file to text using googleapiclient

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to annotate a local image file using google cloud services. I followed the instructions given here https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/libraries, and setup the google API. The given test examples on the page executed without any problem. However, when I am trying to actually annotate a file I am getting error, here is the code I am using:

```
files = [];
files.append("/opt/lampp/htdocs/test.jpg");

def get_text_from_files(fileNames):
    texts = detect_text(fileNames);

def detect_text(fileNames):
    max_results = 6;
    num_retries=3;
    service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('language', 'v1');
    batch_request = [];
    for filename in fileNames:
        request = {
            'image': {},
            'features': [{
                'type': 'TEXT_DETECTION',
                'maxResults': max_results,
            }]
        }

        with open(filename, 'rb') as image_file:
            request['image']['content'] = base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode('UTF-8');
        batch_request.append(request);

    request = service.images().annotate(body={'requests': batch_request});

    try:
        responses = request.execute(num_retries=num_retries)
        if 'responses' not in responses:
            return {};

        text_response = {};
        for filename, response in zip(
                input_filenames, responses['responses']):

            if 'error' in response:
                logging.error('API Error for {}: {}'.format(
                    filename,
                    response['error'].get('message', '')))
                continue

            text_response[filename] = response.get('textAnnotations', [])

        return text_response;

    except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as e:
        print ('Http Error for {}: {}', e)
    except KeyError as e2:
        print ('Key error: {}', e2)


get_text_from_files(files);
```

But I am getting error, I have given the stack trace below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 68, in <module>
    get_text_from_files(pdf);
  File "test.py", line 21, in get_text_from_files
    texts = detect_text(fileNames);
  File "test.py", line 41, in detect_text
    request = service.images().annotate(body={'requests': batch_request});
AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'images'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you are using the wrong Google API Client Python Library. You are using the [Natural Language API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/language/v1), while the one that you want to use is the [Vision API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/vision/v1). The error message `AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'images'` indicates that the resource associated to the Language API does not have any `images` attribute. In order to solve this issue, it should be enough to do the following change:

```
# Wrong API being used
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('language', 'v1');
# Correct API being used
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('vision', 'v1');
```

In this Google API Client Libraries page you will find [the whole list of available APIs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/) and their names and versions available. And here, there's the [complete documentation for the Vision API legacy API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/vision/v1/python/latest/).

Finally, let me recommend you the usage of the [idiomatic Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries) instead of the legacy API Client Libraries. They are much more intuitive to use and there are some good documentation references in [their GitHub page](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/vision/index.html).